# Help on Unknown Currency/Country code

Tags: currency

Are the below valid Current/Country codes:
BML
IPE
IPF
NBR
NUL
NYM

If valid, can you point to the correct source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217) is a list of the ISO 4217 currency codes. None of your codes are mentionned on it.

Besides, none of them are on the [list of ISO 3166 3-digit country codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-3).

Comment: Better to link to ISO page directly https://www.iso.org/iso-4217-currency-codes.html Note that neither of these lists give all codes you need to have the Paid for ISO standard to see all

Comment: Or wikipedia which has the obselete codes as well https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217